# Object object only in production with compiled react

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a webpage built in react, i ecountered a strange problem im  not able to firgure out, this is the code:

```
                    <select id="type" className="selector"
                            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}>
                        <option value="">[Todos las Operaciones]</option>
                        {(searchValues.type).map(type => (
                            <option value={type._id} key={type._id}>
                                    {type._id.length === 2 ? <Fragment>{`Venta/Alquiler`}</Fragment> : <Fragment>{`${type._id[0]}`}</Fragment>}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
```

The data structurue of searchValues.type is like this

```
_id: ["Venta", "Alquiler"]
```

or

```
_id: ["Alquiler"]
```

so the problem is when i run it locally i get the expected results all the options intended but when i compile it i get all [Object object]

Comment: What is `[Object object]`? Is it a string? How did you debug it? The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown where searchValues comes from and what the problem could be.

Comment: Its an array of strings {`${type._id[0]}`}